# run-ios and run-android commands failed

Tags: react-native

Few days ago all was fine and run smoothly.
Today I can’t try my project iOS and Android.
npx react-native run-ios
npx react-native run-android
both commands failed to compile.

I tried to remove node_modules folder, npm install and cd ios pod install
Cleaned the cache and checked if npm package is up to date.

All with no success.
Any help is appreciated and thank you.

Here is the log I get after the failed run-ios command:

0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'react-native',
0 verbose cli   'run-ios'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.2
2 info using node@v14.15.4
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:/Users/aitassouabdelkader/Downloads/_clever-programmer/_projects/_react_projects/_mes_projets/socialMedia/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/aitassouabdelkader/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
19 verbose npm-session f851aed9bb473f1b
20 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
21 timing command:exec Completed in 15519ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
23 verbose pkgid socialMedia@0.0.1
24 verbose cwd /Users/aitassouabdelkader/Downloads/_clever-programmer/_projects/_react_projects/_mes_projets/socialMedia
25 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
26 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "react-native" "run-ios"
27 verbose node v14.15.4
28 verbose npm  v7.5.2
29 error code 1
30 error path /Users/aitassouabdelkader/Downloads/_clever-programmer/_projects/_react_projects/_mes_projets/socialMedia
31 error command failed
32 error command sh -c react-native "run-ios"
33 verbose exit 1

Comment: `(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)`

Exact same error for me, updated xCode on Friday, haven't been able to compile iOs version of our stable React Native project since then.

I can't find any information about this error anywhere except this thread of yours.